# Difference between type[] (array) and [type] (tuple)

Tags: typescript

Lets say we have two interfaces:

```
interface WithStringArray1 {
    property: [string]
}

interface WithStringArray2 {
    property: string[]
}
```

Lets declare some variables of these types:

```
let type1:WithStringArray1 = {
   property: []
}

let type2:WithStringArray2 = {
    property: []
}
```

The first initialisation fails with:

```
TS2322: Type '{ property: undefined[]; }' is not assignable to type 'WithStringArray1'.
Types of property 'property' are incompatible.
Type 'undefined[]' is not assignable to type '[string]'.
Property '0' is missing in type 'undefined[]'.
```

The second one is ok.

What is the difference between `[string]` and `string[]`?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

- `[string]` denotes a tuple with exactly one string element. Tuples are ordered lists of items, finite and usually fixed sized.
- `string[]` denotes an array of strings. Arrays will have variable size, including even a size of zero.

The correct usage of the Tuple in your case would be:

```
let type2:WithStringArray2 = {
    property: ['someString']
};
```

See [Documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types)

Answer (score 4):

if we look tuple with three variable. you can see the difference clearly.

```
let t: [number, string?, boolean?];
t = [42, "hello", true];
```

`let tuple : [string]` is tuple(string) whereas `let arr : string[]`is array of string.