# typescript: any difference between number[] and [number,number]?

Tags: typescript

I'm just learning Typescript and trying to understand best practices for types and interfaces. I am playing with an example using GPS coordinates and want to know if one approach is better than another.

```
let gps1 : number[];
let gps2 : [number, number]
interface Coordinate {
   0: number,
   1: number
}
let gps3 : Coordinate;
```

I suppose the bigger question is if there is a value in typing an array of fixed size & type. Because Typescript does not allow me to easily test if a value is of a certain type on runtime, correct? (i.e. unserialized from a JSON string)

```
gps3 = [1,3]
let check = gps3 instanceof Coordinate;  // doesn't work
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between type\[\] and \[type\] in typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36741917/difference-between-type-and-type-in-typescript)

Comment: No, the title is a bit inconclusive. The thread owner wanted to find out the best way to implement LatLon in TypeScript. maybe the title should be modified to that effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the tuple `[number, number]` doesn't restrict the number of values. It is like `number[]` but with a minimum of two values:

```
let gps2 : [number, number];
gps2 = [1, 2, 3]; // ok
gps2 = [1, 2, 'abc']; // Error: Type [number, number, string] is not assignable to type [number, number]
gps2 = [1]; // Error: Type [number] is not assignable to type [number, number]
```

The interface with numeric keys is like `[number, number]` for the two first values, but it doesn't ensure the type of next values:

```
interface Coordinate {
    0: number,
    1: number
}
let gps3 : Coordinate;
gps3 = [1, 2]; // ok
gps3 = [1, 'abc']; // Error: Type [number, string] is not assignable to type 'Coordinate'
gps3 = [1, 2, 'abc']; // ok
```

Comment: This is structural typing. `[1, 2, 'abc']` is perfectly compatible with `[number, number]`. (In OO terms, it's a subclass).

Comment: @DanielEarwicker `[1, 2, 'abc']` is not compatible with `[number, number]` with TypeScript (tried with 1.8). I wrote this answer because it is an answer for the question: "any difference between number[] and [number,number]?"

Comment: Yes, your answer is very clear. I just think this is a strange inconsistency in TS. For an instance `x` of a tuple type with 2 elements, `x[2]` (with number literal index) should be a type error. But instead TS allows tuples to contain/access further elements as long as they are compatible with the *union* of the specified element's types. This means you can assign a tuple `[number, string, number | string]` to a variable of type `[number, string]`! Also if you have a variable `x` of type `[number, string]` you can get `x[2]` and it will be of type `number|string`.

Comment: It makes sense that `x[y]` (where `y:number`) should have type `number|string` because the value of `y` is unknown at compile time. Now they have number literal types coming in 2.0, maybe `y` ought to be constricted to the type `0|1`, though now this would need a `--strictTuples` flag.

Comment: I found some info in the TS repo that sheds more light on where tuples are headed, so made it into a separate answer.

Answer (score 6):

In your example `gps1` is an array of numbers and `gps2` is [a tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#tuple) of two numbers:

> Tuple types allow you to express an array where the type of a fixed
>   number of elements is known, but need not be the same.

The reason that `gps3 instanceof Coordinate` does not work is that `Coordinate` is an interface and not an actual runtime type.
The compiler user that interface to type check your code, but it does not get translated into javascript.

You can create a [type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards) for that:

```
interface Coordinate {
   0: number,
   1: number
}

function isCoordinate(obj: any): obj is Coordinate {
    return obj instanceof Array && obj.length === 2 && typeof obj[0] === "number" && typeof obj[1] === "number";
}

let a;

if (isCoordinate(a)) {
    console.log(a[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Typescript doesn't allow runtime type checking of interfaces. Instead, you can use your 3rd method by defining `Coordinate` as a class.

```
class Coordinate {
    longitude: number;
    latitude: number;

    constructor(long, lat) {
        this.longitude = long;
        this.latitude = lat;
    }
}
let gps3 = new Coordinate(1,2);

if(gps3 instanceof Coordinate) // true
```

Also, typescript is intended to enforce static typing to otherwise dynamically typed javascript. But your method 2 doesn't necessarily limit the size of the array to 2 elements and `gps2[10]` is still a valid argument (although it's value would be of type `any`).

For readability, I would recommend using the method mentioned above in my answer.

Comment: With this method you can than access latitude and longitude by name with `gps3.latitude` which improves readability in comparison to `gps[1]`.

Comment: This method makes sense to me, and it certainly makes the code easier to read. But it is more work and might be over-the-top for some situations. A 'type guard' might be the next-best option for readability. Still trying to understand what the best practice should be.

Comment: `instanceof` is one of the type guards

Comment: this is technically the answer to my question. but the use of Class or interface is probably the right move.

Answer (score 1):

Well first, the point why you check doesn't work is, that interfaces only exist in TypeScript. In the moment it is executed as JavaScript there is no interface Coordinate anymore. If you would like to use something like this you need to create a class and call it with new.

```ts
class Coordinate extends Array<number> {}

let gps3 = new Coordinate();

gps3.push(1);
gps3.push(3);
let check = gps3 instanceof Coordinate;
```

I personally always use `Array<number>`

1. This notation is also used in other languages
2. When using other generics like for example Observables you also have to use it
3. <strike>It's clearer and you don't have no such kind of confusion with `number[]` `[number]` and `[number, number]` which I think is basically the same.</strike> Okay as the other answers correctly shows it's not the same.

Answer (score 1):

Further to @Paleo's answer on the difference between arrays and tuples, [in a forthcoming version of TS](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/10466) the relationship between tuples, arrays and indexed interfaces has been formalised, so we can now safely say precisely what a tuple is in terms of other features. (I don't think this has changed anything, but before tuples were handled as a special case by the compiler).

A tuple `[T0, T1, T2]` will now be exactly equivalent to:

```
interface Tuple<T0, T1, T2> extends Array<T0 | T1 | T2> {
    0: T0,
    1: T1,
    2: T2
}
```

Note how the array interface is supported, but its element type is the union of all the tuple member types. This makes tuples considerably looser than in other languages; they are (clearly) not pure tuples but are a semi-restricted array. It also means that the array methods (such as `pop`, `push` etc) must all be taken into account by the type checker. Hence:

```
const a: [number, number] = [1, 2, "3"];
```

That is a type error, because the `pop` method of `[1, 2, "3"]` returns `number|string`, where as `a.pop` is supposed to only return `number`.

The inclusion of `Array` in the interface may cause problems for [other future work](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5453), and there is an [open issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6229) suggesting a breaking change to remove it and so make tuples much stricter, i.e. fixed length and without `pop` etc.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm a bit late but best practise would probably be using ECMA6 `Proxy`.

```
    latLngLiteral = new Proxy({},{
        set: function(obj, prop, val) {
            //only these two properties can be set
            if(['lng','lat'].indexOf(prop) == -1) {
                throw new ReferenceError('Key must be "lat" or "lng"!');
            }

            //the dec format only accepts numbers
            if(isNaN(val)) {
                throw new TypeError('Value must be numeric');
            }

            //latitude is in range between 0 and 90
            if(prop == 'lat'  && !(-90 < val && val < 90)) {
                throw new RangeError('Position is out of range!');
            }
            //longitude is in range between 0 and 180
            else if(prop == 'lng' && !(-180 < val && val < 180)) {
                throw new RangeError('Position is out of range!');
            }

            obj[prop] = val;

            return true;
        }
    });
```