# Declaration of array in TypeScript

Tags: arrays, typescript, declaration

I have some experience with TypeScript, but one thing just keeps playing on my mind. I know the difference between `Array<string>` and `string[]`. I know that the declarations can be used interchangeably, f.e.

```
export class SomeClass {

   someDeclaration: Array<SomeObject>;
   otherDeclaration: SomeObject[];

}
```

But in my work, I faced other declaration structure, namely:

```
export class OtherClass {

   strangeDeclaration: [SomeObject];

}
```

**My question is:** Is it correct way to declaring array? Which difference is beetwen this way and other (most popoular) ways? Where does the structure come from?

Comment: An even better question to close against: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36741917/difference-between-type-and-type-in-typescript  And there's this one too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39274045/typescript-any-difference-between-number-and-number-number And this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43225857/typescript-string-vs-string And this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39613923/difference-between-string-and-string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TypeScript arrays can be written `Array<T>` or `T[]` as you suggested.

The other type is a "Tuple". In TS this translated to a index typed array. 
E.g. it's a array with a fixed type at the given position.

Example 'tuple array': `[Number, String]`

[Ts Docs explains this very well](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html)