# TypeScript - [string] vs string[]

Tags: typescript, types

In TypeScript, which one is right?

`[string]` vs `string[]`

```
public searchOption: [string] = ['date'];
public searchOption: string[] = ['date'];
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between type\[\] and \[type\] in typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36741917/difference-between-type-and-type-in-typescript)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The second one is right. If you want, you can take a look here https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html

Comment: I know that this post is 4 years old, but this answer is misleading. The first one is also right for ['date'], see https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types

Answer (score 36):

The first is a [tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html) and the second is an array of strings.

You can do this with tuples:

```
let searchOption: [string, number] = ['date', 22];
```

Answer (score 8):

If all you're going to do is make an array of strings they both seem to behave the same. However the 2nd one is the one you should use.

The first one is so you can make Tuples, like this.

```
let searchOption: [string, number] = ['date', 1];
```

Answer (score 3):

These may appear the same, but they're different.
As has been mentioned by others, the first is a tuple, and the second is an array of strings.

If your array has multiple strings (eg. `['one', 'two', 'three']`) then the second (`string[]` is correct)

If, like in your original post, **you only have one string** in the array, then the first (`[string]`) is correct.