# How to cast an empty array in Typescript to avoid the error "Type never[] canot be converted to type"

Tags: typescript

I get the error `Type never[] canot be converted to type DaySchedule[]` in Visual Studio Code for the following code:

```
class DaySchedule
{
  day: EDay;
  periods: [Period];
}

class WeekSchedule
{
  days: [DaySchedule];
}

const schedule = new WeekSchedule();
schedule.days.push( { day: EDay.Monday, periods: [] as [Period] } );
```

How do I assign an empty array to periods?

Answer (score 0):

This answer explains the problem and links to documentation: [Difference between type[] and [type] in typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36741917/difference-between-type-and-type-in-typescript).

If I change my definitions from `periods: [Periods]` to `periods: Periods[]` it works.

Comment: Instead of answering your own question you should mark it as duplicate of the one you found.