# TypeScript Array differences

Tags: typescript

I'm Kinda new to TypeScript and was wondering what is the difference between,
`let array: SomeClass[];` and
`let array: [SomeClass];`?
What does the different positions of the brackets mean?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between type\[\] and \[type\] in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36741917/difference-between-type-and-type-in-typescript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is to do with the amount of instances in each array

`someClass[]` will mean an array with an infinate length of that class

`[someClass]` will mean a tuple with a length of one of that class

**Ie**
`someClass[]` can be: `[someClass]`, `[someClass, someClass]` or `[someClass, someClass, someClass, someClass]` with any amount of values

Whereas `[someClass]` can only be: `[someClass]` and no other amount of values in the array

Answer (score 0):

`let array: [SomeClass];` defines an array with exaclty one value while `let array: SomeClass[];` defines an array with an undefined number of items

Comment: It's not an array with one value, it's [a tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types)

Comment: A tuple type is another sort of Array type that knows exactly how many elements it contains, and exactly which types it contains at specific positions. Its the same thing. The a tuple by Definition just knows the amount of values in an array. So an array that always has one entry is a tuple and the other way around. JS dosn't support true tupels so every tupel in JS is an array

Comment: A tuple is [a different concept entirely](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuple). It's a  TypeScript happens to realise it through arrays but that doesn't mean an array and duple are the same thing outside of TS.

Comment: Yes but as I said JS does not support Tupels only arrays.